# What is the meaning of servercallback()?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android application but since I am new to android development I do not know  what the meaning of servercallback() is.
Moreover,I am also puzzled as to how the app is able to receive a notification when another user clicks on a button.Like I am working on a cab service app and do not understand as to how is it that when the driver accepts the ride,the user gets a notification about the same.I saw something called a broadcast receiver being but I could not figure out as to which activity is triggering this receiver.Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Here is the application code

```
 jparser.makeHttpRequest(Globals.updateURL, "POST", params, new ServerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                try {
                    success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
                    s = jsonObject.getString("message");

                    if (success == 1) {
                        UserInfo.setName(name);
                        UserInfo.setPhonenumber(number);
                        UserInfo.setPassword(password);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    //  e.printStackTrace();
                    error = 1;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    error = 1;
                }

                pDialog.dismiss();

                if (error == 1) {
                    if (Util.isConnectingToInternet(con)) {
                        Toast.makeText(con, "Server is down, Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else
                        Util.showNoInternetDialog(con);
                    return;
                }

                Toast.makeText(con, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a "callback" is a function that is called when something happens. Programmers call this an event. So your ServerCallback() just allows you to put in codes that is to be executed when you connect to it, for example you could write a code to try to catch any exception when you connect to the server.